# Quarkus - modify JSESSIONID attributes

Tags: quarkus

Is there a way to add SameSite=None attribute to JSSESSIONID cookie. I tried to add `exists(%{o,Set-Cookie}) and regex(pattern="JSESSIONID", value="%{o,Set-Cookie}") -> set(attribute='%{o,Set-Cookie}', value='%{o,Set-Cookie}; Secure; SameSite=None')` in undertow-handlers.conf but it looks like this handler is executed before Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID header is set.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It is not very clean but it works. First I've copied three classes from undertow sources. 
`CookieSameSiteMode.java, SameSiteCookieHandler.java and SameSiteNoneIncompatibleClientChecker.java`. 
Next I changed setting of sameSiteMode property because implementation of setSameSiteMode throws exception when value is not equal to "lax" or "strict" so I've to use reflection to set field value directly. Next I've added undertow-handlers.conf in META-INF directory with content 
`samesite-cookie(mode='None', add-secure-for-none=true)`.
Finally I've added io.undertow.server.handlers.builder.HandlerBuilder file in META-INF/services directory in which I registered my handler. Full example is available on my [github](https://github.com/andrzejszywala/quarkus-samesite)

Comment: Why not submit this to Quarkus as a PR?  This would be a valuable enhancement to Quarkus.

Answer (score 0):

If you use quarkus-undertow, you can use a web.xml.

Put it here: src/main/resources/META-INF

See:
https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#servlet-config

The content can be this to set flags:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553017/setting-httponly-and-secure-in-web-xml](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553017/setting-httponly-and-secure-in-web-xml)