# How to add HttpOnly Attribute for Sensitive Cookies in Jetty Server 8.1.3

Tags: jetty, httponly

I am using Jetty server 8.1.3.

I need to add HttpOnly Attribute for Sensitive Cookies
((ServletContextHandler) context).setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionCookie", "SessionID");

I don't see a property to add httonly attrbiute to session of Servlet context handler.

Any pointer would be great help!!

Thanks

I can see some methods for Jetty server 9 in https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler/getSessionCookieConfig

but can not see for Jetty server 8.1.3

Comment: Jetty Server 8.x was End of Life back in 2014. (and has many vulnerabilities now)

Comment: Previously answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553017/setting-httponly-and-secure-in-web-xml